# How to write code coverage for error block in mocha chai

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I am using Mocha for testing my node js application. Am unable to cover error block of the function. Below one is the code.

```
 public getTaskSummaryByTaskId(req: Request, res: Response, next: 
  NextFunction) {
    let taskId = parseInt(req.query['taskId'], 0);
    new TasksManager().getTaskSummaryByTaskId(taskId).then(results => {
        let data = results[0];
        let taskList: ITaskSummary = {
            Task: (data[0].length === 0 ? null : data[0][0]),
            TaskWorkList: (data[1].length === 0 ? null : data[1]),
            TaskAttachments: (data[2].length === 0 ? null : data[2]),
            TaskAdditionalInfo: (data[3].length === 0 ? null : data[3])
        };
        return Api.ok(req, res, taskList);
    }, err => {
        next(err);
    });
 }
```

Following is the test case which i wrote for the code coverage of above function call. How to cover 'err' block for the above call

```
it('Task Summary By TaskId', () => {
return chai.request(app).get(route + '/taskSummary')
    .query({ taskId: 1000 })
    .then(res => {
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('Task');
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('TaskWorkList');
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('TaskAttachments');
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('TaskAdditionalInfo');
        expect(res).to.be.json;
        expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look into using [sinon js](https://sinonjs.org/) and stubbing in that error. 
It can also be very useful in case you only need to test other functionalities but don't want to wait(like io calls with large objects).

Comment: in case you where wondering sinon is used to fake method/function responses and similar things

Comment: Thank you charbel k. In my case io calls are mandatory. In that scenario how to handle it.

Comment: in the end do you return a value from that error to the main block?